# Running PHP script from the command line

Tags: php, command-line

How can I run a PHP script from the command line using the PHP interpreter which is used to parse web scripts?

I have a `phpinfo.php` file which is accessed from the web shows that `German` is installed. However, if I run the `phpinfo.php` from the command line using - `php phpinfo.php` and `grep` for `German`, I don't find it. So both PHP files are different. I need to run a script which the `php` on which `German` is installed.

How can I do this?

Comment: just do `php -i` and parse that

Comment: What does that mean? I did that nevertheless but nothing

Comment: Please add more **details about installed web server** software, for example add output from `phpinfo();` to your question. Also updated my answer.

Comment: I had the same question as the title (didn't read the rest) and for me the answer was just `php <filename>`

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You should check your server configuration files. Look for lines that start with `LoadModule php`...
There probably are configuration files/directories named `mods` or something like that. Start from there.

You could also check output from `php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep php` and compare lines to `phpinfo();` from web server.

#### To run `php` interactively:

(So you can paste/write code in the console.)

```
php -a
```

#### To make it parse a file and output to the console:

```
php -f file.php
```

#### Parse a file and output to another file:

```
php -f file.php > results.html
```

#### Do you need something else?

To run only a small part, one line or like, you can use:

```
php -r '$x = "Hello World"; echo "$x\n";'
```

If you are running Linux then do `man php` at the console.

If you need/want to run PHP through fpm ([FastCGI Process Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Installation_and_configuration)), use cli fcgi:

```
SCRIPT_NAME="file.php" SCRIP_FILENAME="file.php" REQUEST_METHOD="GET" cgi-fcgi -bind -connect "/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock"
```

Where */var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock* is your php-fpm socket file.

Comment: No. The problem is that there are multiple phps on the system. I need to find out which php is used to parse web scripts. If I run php from the console then it can't find a class - but if I call that script from the web then that problem isn't there. So it means that the PHP which is used are different, isn't it?

Comment: @Siddharth You should check that from your server s/w configuration. Add your server details to question.

Comment: Yes. How can I check that? In short, how can I use the correct php from the command line?

Comment: In linux, you can use `which php` to tell you which executable you are running by default. To use another executable, you must specify the full path to the executable you wish to use: `/path/to/specific/php -f file.php > results.html`

Comment: nice detail, +1 for explanation. Just here to comment, be watch with the environment vars, maybe you need to use the complete directory path even when the script is in the same directory that php.exe

Answer (score 3):

On [SUSE Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUSE_Linux), there are two different configuration files for PHP: one for Apache, and one for CLI (command line interface).  In the */etc/php5/* directory, you will find an "apache2" directory and a "cli" directory.  Each has a "php.ini" file.  The files are for the same purpose (PHP configuration), but apply to the two different ways of running PHP.  These files, among other things, load the modules PHP uses.

If your OS is similar, then these two files are probably not the same.  Your Apache *php.ini* is probably loading the German module, while the the CLI *php.ini* isn't.  When the module was installed (auto or manual), it probably only updated the Apache *php.ini* file.

You could simply copy the Apache *php.ini* file over into the `cli` directory to make the CLI environment exactly like the Apache environment.

Or, you could find the line that loads the German module in the Apache file and copy/paste just it to the CLI file.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a resolution to this issue in Windows, and it seems to be that if you don't have the environment variables ok, you need to put the complete directory. For example, with a file in the same directory as PHP:

```
F:\myfolder\php\php.exe -f F:\myfolder\php\script.php
```

Comment: If you run this verbatim from the command prompt, the `>` at the start will probably redirect the output of `-f ...` (likely an error) into your php.exe file, and wipe the content.