# PHP CMD error : Could not open input file

Tags: php, cmd

I want to run php files using command prompt.For this I set the system variable's path variable(C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16).
After set the path I restart the system and I m trying to run the php file.

I typed

```
php test.php
```

But its says

```
Could not open input file
```

Comment: this might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262532/running-php-script-from-the-command-line

Comment: What is the command that you enter in the prompt?

Comment: Please, add that to your question.

Comment: did you check the path after the restart?

Comment: @Stephan :Yes I check it out ..

Comment: Are you in the folder where the test.php file is? Setting the path will make windows find the PHP.EXE but it needs a fully defined path to the php code you are trying to execute.

Answer (score -2):

Run:

```
pear
```

it will set %PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN% for you.

Comment: Not getting you.How to run that ?What is use of it ?

Comment: not getting you too. What is use of it?

Comment: %PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN% is a save directory. but I don't know what he wants to say with this.