# PHP with CMD display data when add variable

Tags: php

I have `test.php` like below:

```
<?
    class Track{

        public function displaySong($title, $duration){

            $data = $title + $duration

            return $data;
        }

    }
?>
```

how to run it on CMD?... like if i do like this with cmd

```
song1 = Track("Britney - Toxic", "0:3:51")
song2->displaySong()
```

It returns

```
Song :  Britney - Toxic, Duration:  0:3:51
```

on cmd display

Comment: [Are you asking how to execute a PHP file via CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262532/running-php-script-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running PHP script from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262532/running-php-script-from-the-command-line)

Comment: nope, ham asking how to make my script work. its error `('`

Comment: Well, could provide the error? The expected output?

Comment: when I execute `song1 = Track("Britney - Toxic", "0:3:51")` its return `syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: Please; reread; your; code; it is a very; simple; mistake;

Comment: Secondly, where is your constructor? Why are you passing values to `Track` without a constructor to mange them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you should use "",this is a suggestion php.net give
   [image] (this is been blocked by stackoverflow)

   2. you have an error at this : 
      "$data = $title + $duration" => "$data = $title + $duration;"
   3. if you want run a php file in CMD, you need use as : php test.php argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3okw.png) argv[2] ... , argv is the data you want to give the test.php
   4. and the last , your test.php should add some code:

      ```
        public function displaySong($title, $duration){

           $data = $title + $duration;

           echo $data;
        }
      ```

      }
        $song = new Track();
        $song->displaySong($argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3okw.png), $argv[2]);

Comment: I run this php file and I get a result                     ➜  ~ php c.php 1 2
3