# How can I run a php file on visual studio code for linux

Tags: php

I am trying to start learning php but I can not run the file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first PHP page</h1>

<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the basic code and I saved it as `test.php`. When I type `php -f test.php` it gives me the error `"Could not open input file: test.php"`.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running PHP script from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262532/running-php-script-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Try starting PHP's internal web server: From the folder where your 'test.php' file is, run `php -S localhost:8088` (This will start the server on the port 8088). Then, open your internet browser and type `http://localhost:8088/test.php` in your address bar. You should see the hello world example.

Comment: go to your directory and try again